# Import data into Power BI from rest Api with date range

Tags: api, powerbi

I am trying to get data into Power BI desktop version from a rest Api. I want that it should always import the  last 3 months data dynamically. I have written the below code in the advanced editor:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://xyz",[Headers=[Authorization="123", #"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="321"]],startDate=2023-05-12T00:00:00.000Z&endDate=" & Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T00:00:00.000Z")), 65001),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded errors" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "errors"),
    #"Expanded errors1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded errors", "errors", {"message", "type"}, {"errors.message", "errors.type"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded errors1",{{"errors.message", type text}, {"errors.type", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

However, it's giving an error message. Could someone please help me with this code. Thanks in advance.